# Login Required not working

Tags: html

I want this feature in my website... 
In the login page if i don't fill the Input Form(Name,Password....) and click the LOGIN Button
It must give a alert "Required space is empty"
When i fill the Input Form and i click on the login button it must go to my next page.

```
<form>
      <div>
         <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" Required> <br> <br>   

         <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
         <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" Required> <br> <br>

         <label> <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me <br> <br> </label>
         <button type="submit"> <a href="test.html">Login</a>  </button><br> <br>
      </div>
</form>
```

Now what happening is that when i click on "LOGIN" Button it does not give any alert of "Required space is empty", 
instead it goes to nest page "test.html"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `a` element from the `submit` button.

If you want to redirect to `test.html` when fields are filled out, use the `action` attribute of the `form` element.

```html
<form action="test.html">
  <div>
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" Required> <br> <br>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" Required> <br> <br>

    <label> <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me <br> <br> </label>
    <button type="submit">Login</button><br> <br>
  </div>
</form>
```